# Guitar tuner app for Android

Tags: android, audio

Does anyone know where to get a guitar tuner app for an Android device, but not from the Play store? I don't use the Play store, only alternative app stores.

I found a few but the security of them was less than ideal.

Comment: It would be a good idea to add the ones you found, so others don’t recommend them (or recommend them, and point out why there is no security issue).

Answer (score 0):

You can find apps for Android [plus](https://apkrabi.com/ar/) at APKRabi

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/63244)

Answer (score -1):

You may use web services for downloading apps from Play Store like:
https://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/ (seems like it's never working for me lately)
or https://apkpure.com/

also there is Raccoon - APK downloader app for desktops
http://www.onyxbits.de/raccoon

also there was some kind of Chrome extension which added "Download" button in Play Store website

also you may use warez sites, some of them host free apps too